# Asynchronously setting MKAnnotationView wrong images

Tags: mapkit, mkannotationview

I'm asynchronously loading images via AWS S3 and setting the `MkMapView` image to this image. My s3 code is long but it works everywhere else-and I think I narrowed this down to a `@synchronized` problem. I'm using this because in my `didSelectAnnotationView`, I'm rearranging my `NSMutableArray` which requires thread safety.

My steps are as follows. First, whenever the map screen changes, I download the users in that area and parse the JSON repsonse. I set these responses to an `NSMutableArray` via

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

    @synchronized(self.trainerArray){
        [self.trainerArray removeAllObjects];

        for(NSDictionary* item in tempDict){
            FSTrainer* tempTrainer = [[FSTrainer alloc] initWith:item];

            //adding to temp array and map
            [self.trainerArray addObject:tempTrainer];
            TrainerPin* trainerPin = [[TrainerPin alloc] initWith:tempTrainer];
            [self.mapView addAnnotation:trainerPin];
        }
    }
  }
```

Now when I set this via the `viewForAnnotation` (with custom reuse identifiers) this all works fine, UNLESS I zoom really fast or erratically, and then the same image gets set twice (the first one).

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView: (MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation: (id) annotation {    
    TrainerPin* trainerPinForView = (TrainerPin*)annotation;

    TrainerMapImage *pin = (TrainerMapImage *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"trainerAnnotation%ld", (long)trainerPinForView.trainer.id]];
    if (!pin) {
        pin = [[TrainerMapImage alloc] initWithAnnotation: trainerPinForView reuseIdentifier: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myPin%ld", (long)trainerPinForView.trainer.id]];
    } else {
        pin.annotation = trainerPinForView;
    }

    //custom method in TrainerMapImage
    [pin asyonchronouslySetImage];

    return pin;
}
```

Another thing to note is that wrapping this in a GCD queue ALWAYS returns the first image for every `MKMapView`

Comment: because it is a reusable control. You should store images somewhere locally or in the memory and then get an image from this cache by annotation id